# Stop periodic function calls on event

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, iot

I am working on an IoT device that has a continuously running function sequence. The device can also receive commands and execute them. While I can have both these "sections" running on their own, I'm having trouble trying to have both these things run simultaneously. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
//all required imports
var handler = new events.EventEmitter.call(this)
function step0(){
  //do something
  if(err) {setTimeout(step0, 1500); return; }
  step1(result);
}

function step1(){
  //do something
  if(err) {setTimeout(step0, 1500); return; }
  step2(result);
}

function step2(){
  //do something
  if(err) {setTimeout(step0, 1500); return; }
  console.log(result);
}

var timeOutID = setTimeout(step0, 1500);

//END of loop tasks
aws.device.on('message', function(payload, topic){
    clearTimeout(timeOutID);  
    handler.emit(payload.command);  
})

handler.on('command1', function(){
   /*do something*/
   setTimeout(step0, 1500);
});
handler.on('command2', function(){
   /*do something*/
   setTimeout(step0, 1500);
});
handler.on('command3', function(){
   /*do something*/
   setTimeout(step0, 1500);
});
```

The issue I am facing is that there appears to be a race condition between - the "step" functions get invoked while the "command" event handlers are executing. I am fairly new to nodeJS so I'm not sure if this the right way to go about it.

Comment: Does the `// do something` part concern some async code? Where are `err` and `result` coming from?

Comment: Yes, there are some aync calls made to the serialport but these are wrapped in Promises. For example `//do something is:` `sensor.ledOn().then( function(){ step1(); },  function(){ return; })`.

Comment: Well then the code that is after the `// do something` needs to be wrapped inside the `then` callback of those promises, otherwise it won't wait for the resolution.